# Building MySQL Query with Access

Tags: mysql

I have the following query and it comes up with an error

```
SELECT CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta, CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_VendedorAsignado, Sum([Precio]*(100-[CRM_PresupuestosDetalles].[Bonif])/100*[CRM_PresupuestosDetalles].[Cantidad]) AS LineaNeto
FROM CRM_PRESUPUESTOS RIGHT JOIN CRM_PresupuestosDetalles ON CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_Presupuesto = CRM_PresupuestosDetalles.ID_Presupuesto
GROUP BY CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta, CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_VendedorAsignado
HAVING ((DATE((CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta))=CurDate()));
```

The error is

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Precio]*(100-[CRM_PresupuestosDetalles].[Bonif])/100*[CRM_PresupuestosDetalles‌​]' at line 1

How can I fix this? The problem probably is that I'm building them with Access

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Precio]*(100-[CRM_PresupuestosDetalles].[Bonif])/100*[CRM_PresupuestosDetalles]' at line 1

Comment: Have changed my query, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets, `[` `]`, are t-sql specific. They tell the parser that the contained text is a string and keeps you safe from potentially mistakenly using a t-sql reserved word. The MySql similar way of doing this is with backticks: `

```
SELECT CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta, 
CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_VendedorAsignado, 
Sum(`Precio`*(100-`CRM_PresupuestosDetalles`.`Bonif`)/100*`CRM_PresupuestosDetalles`.`Cantidad`) AS LineaNeto
FROM CRM_PRESUPUESTOS RIGHT JOIN CRM_PresupuestosDetalles ON CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_Presupuesto = CRM_PresupuestosDetalles.ID_Presupuesto
GROUP BY CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta, CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_VendedorAsignado
HAVING ((DATE((CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta))=CurDate()));
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds unrelated to your query syntax. If you need help with that too, you might want to post another question. Good luck :)

Comment: here you go... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709670/mysql-error-2003-when-using-navicat

Comment: Sorry, not sure what the issue is. But if you feel this answered your query issue, please consider checking the accepted answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, don't know if you saw my comment on the other post but this query works.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this::

```
SELECT 
CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta, 
CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_VendedorAsignado, 
Sum(Precio*(100-CRM_PresupuestosDetalles.Bonif/100*CRM_PresupuestosDetalles.Cantidad) AS LineaNeto

FROM CRM_PRESUPUESTOS RIGHT 
JOIN CRM_PresupuestosDetalles ON CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_Presupuesto = CRM_PresupuestosDetalles.ID_Presupuesto

GROUP BY CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta, CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.ID_VendedorAsignado
HAVING DATEDIFF(CRM_PRESUPUESTOS.Fecha_Alta, CurDate)=0
```

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Precio]*(100-[CRM_PresupuestosDetalles].[Bonif])/100*[CRM_PresupuestosDetalles]' at line 4

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.(Bonif))/100*(CRM_PresupuestosDetalles).(Cantidad)) AS LineaNeto

FROM CRM_PR' at line 4