# MySQL error 2003 when using Navicat

Tags: mysql, navicat

I connect to my MySQL database using Navicat. I've just got an error

```
[Err] 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'www.website.com' (10061)
```

I connect to the database using port 3306. I can't edit any admin settings as it's hosted on a  shared server, inmotion.com

This occurred after having an error with a query. Possible max connection error? It's set at 10 but I can't edit it because of the shared server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means that the DB is unresponsive. Restarting `mysqld` process should fix this.

Comment: But how do I that? It's hosted on inmotion

Comment: Hm.. If there is no DB restart button in the admin control panel, then perhaps you can contact them? 

If it's a shared hosting, then the DB should be unresponsive for everyone else at the moment.

Comment: I think they (inmotion) where working on the database on another problem I have. It workes now. Thanks